# .NET Threading issue, TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, memory-leaks, tcpclient

My service's thread count is going bonkers.

I create new tcpclient every time a connection is needed. that is handled by taskfactory, with longrunning task flag.

I use 2 concurrent bags and manualresetevents, the code disposes of objects properly and nothing is left hanging (to my knowledge).

The problem only occurs on windows xp machine, windows 7 is ok. So I guess it is not the code.

Is there any way to check how busy is the threadpool on a PC?

I have already posted about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622114/taskfactory-tcpclient#comment17019767_12622114)

Any advice greatly appreciated.

[image: Attached screenshot shows the problem]

Thanks Luke

Answer (score 2):

Try getting available threads from the ThreadPool : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getavailablethreads%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

If you are developing a non-amateur solution, I would suggest you to not to give your back to the ThreadPool. instead you may have couple of threads (or more) shared among the clients.